# Where can I find the jni headers for Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface

I'm not asking where I can find it on **my own computer**, I'm asking where I can get it.

I've done my google homework, and I didn't find the headers in those paths. There wasn't even a Header folder in my /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/... and stuff and I don't have a Developer folder under root.

Now I'm pretty sure I don't have those headers installed, I checked the MacOS developer website but I only found some broken links.

Shouldn't OpenJDK or SunJDK provide the jni.h header for MacOS somewhere?

Comment: what's wrong with http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html ?

Comment: @manuell Yes, that's where I got my JDK. But the jni.h wasn't included in the mac DMG

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/jni.h`

But this depends on your environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, there wasn't a Headers directory. I removed JDK entirely and reinstalled, and it was there as you says.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `java_home` command to find the correct location. See the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html).

So for example in your makefile you could have:

```
JAVA_HOME:=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
CPPFLAGS:=-I $(JAVA_HOME)/include -I $(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin
```

Note that you also need to add `$(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin` to the include path so it can find `jni_md.h` which is the machine-specific part and is included by `jni.h`

Answer (score 8):

1. jdk8 download web url:
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

download it and install.

2. check java version:

> ```
> sodino:~ sodino$ java -version 
> java version "1.8.0_45" 
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14) 
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
> ```

3.find 'java' original path and ‘java_home':

> ```
> sodino:~ sodino$ which java
> /usr/bin/java
> sodino:~ sodino$ ls -n /usr/bin/java
> lrwxr-xr-x  1 0  0  74 Sep 30  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
> sodino:~ sodino$/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
> ```

4. get ‘include’ folder and jni.h

   now you will find a ‘include’ folder with in ‘/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home’,
   and open it ‘jni.h’  will be found.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS X 10.8.5, I use "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers", like:

```
HelloJNI.o : HelloJNI.c HelloJNI.h
gcc -I"/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers" -fpic -c $< -o $@
```

BTW, I am using this version of Java:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```