# Fatal Error: 'jni.h' File Not Found On Mac OSX 10.11.6

Tags: c++, macos, java-native-interface

So I've been trying to follow [this](http://mrjoelkemp.com/2012/01/getting-started-with-jni-and-c-on-osx-lion/) guide to using JNI and native methods on Mac, and I give terminal the command

> g++ "-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Headers"
>   "-I/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers"
>   -c HelloWorld.cpp

as stated in the guide. However, upon doing this I get the message "fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found.

Is this because the guide is outdated? If so, what is the current command to be used?

Comment: Just saying, that SDK reference is for snow leopard. You seem to be running El Capitain. Chances are the SDK location has changed (if its there at all; I honestly didn't check).

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, only I don't know where I would find the new SDK location.

Comment: Check under /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines on your install drive. At least that's where mine starts on High Sierra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find the jni headers for Mac OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771803/where-can-i-find-the-jni-headers-for-mac-os)