# JNI header missing in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, java-native-interface

I have a `file.c` in my project which has `#include <jni.h>` header file. What is the process to include this header file in project or macOS?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20783713/1040347) answer your question?

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov i found location of header file in system folder.but i am struggling to connect that header file with xCode

Comment: In Xcode open Build Settings and check the `header search paths`, there should be the path to your library.
 [This might](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428303/1040347) answer your question

Comment: @ AlekseyPotapov your suggestion helped me to fix the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding system header search path to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode)

Comment: Moderation: I just marked the question as duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make jni.h be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529720/how-to-make-jni-h-be-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have following code

```
#include "jni.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        JNIEnv *env;
        JavaVM *jvm;
        JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
        JavaVMOption options[3];

        options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=_HERE_GOES_LOCATION_OF_JNICOOKBOK_/jnicookbook/recipeNo051/target";

        vm_args.options = options;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
        vm_args.nOptions = 1;           

        int status = JNI_CreateJavaVM (&jvm, (void **) &env, &vm_args);
        if (status < 0 || !env) {
          printf ("Error - JVM creation failed\n");
          return 1;
        }

        jclass cls_Main = (*env)->FindClass (env, "recipeNo051/Main");

        jmethodID method_displayMessage = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID (env, cls_Main, "displayMessage", "()V");
        (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls_Main, method_displayMessage);

        (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM( jvm );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

in order to run it you will need

- location of `libjvm.dylib`
- location of headers
- location of compiled Java classes that are called from `main.m`

Let's start with libs and headers. You have to make sure that following paths are searched for includes (note that I am using jdk-11.0.4):

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/include
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin/
```

You have to make sure that following path is added to `Library Search Path` and to `Runpath Search Paths`

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server
```

You should have settings like that:

[image]

Make sure you are linking your code with `libjvm.dylib`. Add it inside `Build Phases`

[image]

where you can specify it's location by choosing `Add Other...`

[image]

Run your code, but! Make sure to ignore `SIGSEGV` before calling method `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. You can ignore it inside `lldb` console

```
(lldb) process handle --pass true --stop false SIGSEGV
```

[image]

After you continue, you can see your `JVM` instance calling classes from the `recipeNo051`.

[image]

Source code of class: `recipeNo051/Main` can be found here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo051

**Update**

- step by step instructions: http://www.owsiak.org/running-jni-based-code-inside-xcode/
- video tutorial: https://youtu.be/WEA-3uI7Y18